# What HTML5 features does Droptiles by Omar AL Zabir support?

Tags: java, php, html, microsoft-metro

Id like to create an HTML5 web apps/site which could be consumed on Desktop, tablet and Mobile devices.  I want it to be flexible in such a way that I could use PHP or Java with it. After intensive googling I found Droptiles (droptiles.com) by Omar Al Zabir. Since I was also thinking of incorporating the Windows Live Tiles look and functionality in my mobile web site, I think that it is a good choice.  My question is what are the HTML5 features which are supported by Droptiles?  I need to know this before commiting to this framework.  So far reading its documentation I have not read of any html5 feature.  I hope people with experience using Droptiles could answer my question.  Thanks in advance.

By the way the html5 features that I consider as deal breakers are

- offline storage
- support for viewport meta tag ( or anything that would allow it to scale depending on the device used)
- html5 input types (email,phone number, calendar etc)

Comment: Why not to ask the author directly?

Answer (score 0):

If you have an existing website, you can load the website in c# with the webview element.

The droptiles is build with html5/javascript. So everything must work fine.
Only the HTML5 type=color is not supported in Windows IE engine

Comment: I saw the authors web presentation and there he used html5 tools and libraries such as modernizer and bootstrap but when I tried to view the demo on my android tablet running ICS with a chrome browser it didnt behave like a normal html5 web app.  It failed to scale properly but appeared zoomed out instead.  I thought that even a basic html5 webapp could have scaled properly, that is why I had doubts on its html5 feature support.